Typescript compiler not narrowing return type
I am trying to write a typescript function which takes as input a type ABC from which I require a subset of properties to compute another to augment the returned value.
I want the input to be nullable, and the semantics of the types should express that if a non-nullable value is passed in the return value will be non-null, and if null is passed, the response will also be null.
The function I've implemented seems to work, and the compiler inference on the call side seems to be working as I would expect, but in the implementation of the function, I can't figured out how to let the compiler understand that if I narrow on input such that I know the input is null, the returned value should also be null.
type ABC = {
  a: string;
  b: string | null;
  c: string;
};

export const getwithABC = <T extends Pick<ABC, "a" | "b"> | null>(
  input: T
): T extends Pick<ABC, "a" | "b">
  ? NonNullable<T> & { ab: string | null }
  : T extends null
  ? null
  : never => {
  if (!input) {
    // @ts-ignore I can't figure out how to make the compiler understand that this is a valid return type
    // The calling code does correctly infer the right return type
    return null;
  }

  const { a, b } = input;

  return {
    ...input,
    ab: b ? `${a}/${b}` : null,
  } as T extends Pick<ABC, "a" | "b"> & { ab: string | null }
    ? NonNullable<T> & { ab: string | null }
    : never;
};

Any ideas how this can be expressed?

From my experience, TS is not really meant to be used that way.
The simpler approach is to give the function type overloads.
type ABC = {
  a: string;
  b: string | null;
  c: string;
};

export function getwithABC<T extends Pick<ABC, "a" | "b">>(
  input: T
): T & { ab: T["b"] };

export function getwithABC(
  input: null
): null;

export function getwithABC<T extends Pick<ABC, "a" | "b"> | null>(
  input: T
): (T & { ab: string | null }) | null {
  if (!input) {
    return null;
  }

  const { a, b } = input;

  return {
    ...input,
    ab: b ? `${a}/${b}` : null,
  }
};

It works by making a general function that can handle all overloads. Then giving overloads that can narrow the return type based on the input arguments.

TypeScript 5.8 will very likely fix this issue.
Generic functions that return conditional types are currently (as of TypeScript 5.6) hard for the type checker to verify, as described in microsoft/TypeScript#33912. That's because it does not use control flow analysis to affect the generic type parameter T, and therefore the conditional types are still unevaluated in the return statements.  TypeScript really has no idea what might be assignable to T extends Pick<ABC, "a" | "b"> ? NonNullable<T> & { ab: string | null } : T extends null ? null : never until T is specified.
microsoft/TypeScript#33912 was recently fixed when microsoft/TypeScript#56941 was merged into the main branch. This is set to be released with TypeScript 5.8. When this happens, generic functions that return distributive conditional types of the form T extends X1 ? Y1 : T extends X2 ? Y2 : ⋯ T extends XN ? YN : never can use control flow analysis to narrow T in the case that T is constrained to X1 | X2 | ⋯ | XN and T is the type of exactly one function parameter and you check the value of that type.  You can read the description of microsoft/TypeScript#56941 for more information, and very likely the release notes for TypeScript 5.8 when they are available.
Beacuse T is constrained to Pick<ABC, "a" | "b"> | null, and because the return type T extends Pick<ABC, "a" | "b"> ? NonNullable<T> & { ab: string | null } : T extends null ? null : never is a distributive conditional type of the required form, and because T is the type of input, and because you are checking input for null, all of the requirements for microsoft/TypeScript#56941 are met and the function implementation can now be checked the way you expected in the first place. In other words, your code compiles without error as-is:
Playground link to TS 5.8.0-dev.20241106

Amazing. Thanks for the extra info.  Glad to see I was on the right lines with what I was trying to do and that the ts team is already on it!
